# React input type number with comma as decimal separator

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I tried to set value in 'German' locale to react input number field as below;

My value got reset and gives below warning in chrome console.

'The specified value "2345,00" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?'

[image]

I am using react 15.6.1 It seems ReactDOMInput doesn't support comma as decimal separator. Does anyone have solution for this issue?

Comment: try changing your browser's language and check what happens ;) most likely it will get resolved. if someone needs to see the numbers in german format most likely will have their language set to that locale